# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje de error al rebasar el máximo de caracteres en un mat input?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Tengo en la siguiente tabla el campo **descripción** el cual es editable, ya le establecí con la propiedad **maxlength** el No. de caracteres que debe de permitir y ya no deja ingresar más, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el usuario siga tratando de escribir, se muestre un mensaje en color rojo que diga "El tamaño maximo es de 15 caracteres"

```
    <mat-expansion-panel>
                    <button mat-raised-button class="buttonUpdate" color="primary"
                        (click)="obtenerProductos()">Actualizar
                        <mat-icon>update</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title class="text">
                            Productos
                        </mat-panel-title>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <div class="scrollme">
                        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceProd" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID  </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
                            </ng-container>
    
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcion">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
                                        <input matInput type="text" [value]="element.descripcion"
                                            (keyup)="changeValueDescTipo($event.target,element)"
                                            
                                            [disabled]="!element.editable">
                                    </mat-form-field>
<span class="error" *ngIf="e.limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo para este campo es de 15</span>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
    
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="botonEdit">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> EDITAR </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="actualizarProd(element,tipoProductoModelo)">
                                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
    
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="botonDelete">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ELIMINAR </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <button mat-icon-button color="warn"
                                    (click)="eliminarProductos($event.target,element)">
                                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
    
                            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsProd"></tr>
                            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsProd">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <mat-paginator #paginatorCatalogos [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5]"
                        showFirstLastButtons>
                     </mat-paginator>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
```

component.ts

```
     changeValueDescTipo(e: any, row: any) {
       this.idSelecc = row.id;
       this.tipoProductoDesc = e.value;
    
       if (this.tipoProductoDesc.length > 15) {
           e.limiteExcedido = true;
           e.target.value =  this.tipoProductoDesc.slice(0, 15);
        } else {
          e.limiteExcedido = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con un valor booleano. Lo primero sería inicializar una variable global booleana establecida en `false` en tu TS:

```
limiteExcedido = false;
```

Y un `<span>` debajo de tu `input` descripción, que incluimos la directiva `*ngIf`, que quiere decir que se mostrará ese `<span>` si la variable booleana está en `true`.

```html
<span class="error" *ngIf="limiteExcedido">El tamaño máximo es de 15 caracteres</span>
```

Vemos que agregamos una clase llamada `error`, es solo para darle estilo CSS:

```
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

A tu input, quitemos el `maxlength`, ya que con el `maxlength` solo podemos escribir hasta 15 caracteres, y la idea es mostrar el mensaje si superamos los 15 caracteres:

```
<input matInput type="text" [value]="element.descripcion 
      (keyup)="changeValueDescTipo($event.target,element)"
      [disabled]="!element.editable">
```

Entonces lo que podríamos hacer es validar que si la longitud del valor de lo que escribimos supera a 15, hacemos un `slice` para obtener los primeros 15 caracteres (así borrando el último caracter, simulando el comportamiento del `maxlenght`) y establecemos el valor booleano a `true` para mostrar el mensaje de error (tu `<span>`). Tu función del `(keyup)` quedaría algo así:

```
limiteExcedido: boolean = false;

changeValueDescTipo(event: any, element: any) {
  const inputValue: string = event.target.value;

  if (inputValue.length > 15) {
    this.limiteExcedido = true;
    event.target.value = inputValue.slice(0, 15);
  } else {
    this.limiteExcedido = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Hola ya lo apliqué y si me funcionó, gracias.  Solo un problema, al ingresar más caracteres de lo establecido sale el mensaje de error en todos los registros de la tabla, y solo quiero que aparezca en el registro donde estoy haciendo la edicion., como puedo corregir eso

Comment: ya modifique mi pregunta a como lo cambie en mi component.ts, y en el html, pero al cargar la pagina dice en el navegador ---- > ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'limiteExcedido') y marca la linea donde esta el <span>

Comment: En tu `<span>` creo que tiene que ser `*ngIf="element.limiteExcedido"`, si el error persiste, prueba cambiando los `e.limiteExcedido` por `row.limiteExcedido` de tu función.